# How to use google maps api to get current location?

Tags: reactjs, api, google-maps, geolocation

I am building a website using React JS. I need to get the user's location for API call.

I used `navigator.geolocation.`

```
navigator.geolocation.getcurrentPosition
```

I could get the location, but it asks for the user's permission.
I don’t want to ask users for permissions.

I think I can use google maps API directly. I have a google maps API key. But I could not find the solution. How can I solve it?

Comment: You cannot negate the prompt for permission and nor should you try to fool your users as a matter of courtesy. [Read more about this](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be to call the getLocation() on window.load. You could also attach it to the  tag like this .

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

window.onload = getLocation;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
          "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
     break;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that way. But that also uses navigator. I think that is supported by the browser. That also asks for the user's permission.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354472/how-can-i-get-users-location-without-asking-for-the-permission-or-if-user-permi/36494235

Then please try this.