# Wordpress - How to get device type and last login location with php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I wrote this function that allows the user to view the date of the last login (not the current login). Now I would also like to show the location and device with which the login was made. I tried to search but could not find any solution to my problem. Can anyone shed some light on this? I appreciate any help.

```
// Function that set last login
add_action('wp_login', 'set_last_login', 0, 2);
function set_last_login($login, $user) {
  $user = get_user_by('login',$login);
  $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
  $last_login = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', 'true' );
  if(!$last_login) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time );
  } 
   else {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login_prev', $last_login );
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time );
  }
}

// Function that get last login
function get_last_login($user_id, $prev = null) {
  $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id);
  $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
  if(isset($last_login['_last_login_prev'][0]) && $prev) {
  $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, '_last_login_prev', 'true' );
  } 
  else if(isset($last_login['_last_login'][0])) {
    $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, '_last_login', 'true' );
  } 
  else {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_last_login', $time );
    $last_login = $last_login['_last_login'][0];
  } return $last_login;
}
```

Trying to get something like this
[image]

Comment: You can get the device from the user session metadata. Location, at least in Europe, is prompt to accept based, meaning the browser won't share the location of the user. You (the user) need to accept to share the location.

Comment: The answers to these questions (device type, geolocation) are surprisingly vast.  I suggest you deal with them one at a time. There are plugins for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of context, location is "Accept to share" based, on browsers (at least on desktop), meaning after a prompt from the browser, you (the user) need to accept to share your location.

You should be able to get the latitude and longitude through javascript via the [Location Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and then get the adress from the [Nominatim OpenStreetMap API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/).

We could then pass everything to PHP through ajax and store it as a user metadata.

---

### Basic example

> **The following is not production ready. It is a working proof of concept.**

#### Retrieving the user location

First thing first, to use [Ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) we need [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/). We also need to pass the Ajax url to our script to be able to process the request. We will also need to pass [Nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) for security reason. This is done through the [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) function.

```
<?php

/**
 * Enqueue jquery.
 *
 * @see https://releases.jquery.com/
 */
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-min', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js', array(), '3.6.1', true );

//Add jquery integrity key
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

    if ( 'jquery-min' === $handle ) {

        $tag = str_replace(
            "></script>",
            " integrity='sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>",
            $tag
        );

    };

    return $tag;

}, 10, 3 );

//Enqueue my-script
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery-min' ), wp_get_theme()->version, true );

/**
 * Pass the ajax admin url and a freshly generated nonce to our script.
 *
 * Apparently we should now use wp_add_inline_script instead of wp_localize_script to expose a global object that needs to be used by your script.
 * @see Jules Colle comment in the User Contributed Notes section.
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/#user-contributed-notes
 */
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'localize', array(
    '_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    '_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( '_ajax_nonce' ),
) );
```

As we said before, we can use the [Nominatim OpenStreetMap API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/), which is free (currently end of 2022), to reverse the location based on the latitude and longitude, and send the result to our backend for processing.

```js
if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
    
    /**
     * Use the browser Geolocation API.
     * Prompt the user to share his location.
     * 
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API
     */
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( position ) {

        let lat = position.coords.latitude;
        let lon = position.coords.longitude;

        /**
         * Reverse geocoding.
         * 
         * @https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/
         */
        $.getJSON(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=${ lat }&lon=${ lon }`, function( object ) {
            
            let adress = object.address;
            
            //Send the ajax request.
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: localize._ajax_url,
                data: {
                    _ajax_nonce: localize._ajax_nonce,
                    action: '_wpso_73934145',
                    openStreetMapObject: adress,
                },
                success: function ( response ) {
                    console.log( response.data );
                },
            } );
        } );
    } );
};
```

Our javascript ajax request needs to be answered by our PHP action function which will trigger our [update_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/) function.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax__wpso_73934145', function () {

    if ( check_ajax_referer( '_ajax_nonce' ) ) {

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  
        $openStreetMapObject = $_POST['openStreetMapObject'];

        $meta_key = '_user_position';

        $meta_value = array(
            'openStreetMapObject' => $openStreetMapObject,
        );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );

        wp_send_json_success( $meta_value );

    } else {

        wp_send_json_error();

    };

    wp_die();

} );
```

On the front end we can access our metadata through [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/).

```
<?php

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$meta_key = '_user_position';

if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user_id, $meta_key ) ) {

    $meta_value = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true);

    var_dump( $meta_value );

    var_dump( $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']['city_district'] );

} else {
    
    echo 'You need to share your location';

};
```

---

#### Retrieving the user device

In regards to the device we can retrieve the user agent. To decrypt the user agent and understand what it stand for I would suggest reading the [Mozzila User-Agent developer documentation guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', function () {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        var_dump( $user_agent );

    };

} );
```

---

### Alternatives

Reverse search the user IP which would let us retrieve the user approximate location without prompting them.

- @see https://www.geoplugin.com/ and [How to get the client IP address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3003145/3645650).
- @see [How can I get user's location without asking for the permission or if user permitted once so need not to ask ever again?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26354472/3645650).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it can work. But I have a doubt about the device and the user agent. If I use the function as you wrote it should show the device of the currently logged in user, but that's not what I need to do. I need to capture the device used at login moment and view it later. Just like with the date and with the geolocation example you wrote.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I'm trying to use your advice but I don't understand where to put certain things. I created my-ajax-script and put the js geolocation code. Then enqueue script, localize script and ad_action I put them in functions.php. But all of this is not working. Am I doing something wrong ? Also, how can I view the location on screen?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. The last thing, I have everything in child-theme, so I should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()` right?

Comment: Hey @amarinediary I would still like to thank you for the tremendous help you have provided me. Either way, I have a little problem. The result I was looking for initially was to view the location of the last login, instead as we did yesterday in the chat I'm always getting the current location. Do you have any suggestions for setting the location at the last login as is happening for the dates?

Comment: @Snorlax I thought about it, and I don't think, with the current approach, (retrieving the user exact adress) that it is actually possible as the user NEEDS to share his location. I've explained a possible alternative in the last edit. I've created a github repo using the ip reverse geolocation https://github.com/amarinediary/wpso73934145.

Answer (score 1):

**Detect Location:**

You might want to consider using the [HTML5 Geolocoation API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

Otherwise, the IP may tell you something about the location:
[How to get Real IP from Visitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor)

Other options for location detection includes:

[Geolocator-PHP](https://sourceforge.net/directory/development/development/)

[Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

[Maxmind (php)](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolocate-an-ip/web-services?lang=en)

**Detect Device:**

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/

https://www.codexworld.com/mobile-device-detection-in-php/

http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided. You can refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)